# Trying to add a new element to the navigation bar and a new page to a website [Can't find the error]

Tags: html, css, web

I am re-using a Twitter Bootstrap theme in order to create a website. I am a beginner in web design and I know this might sound trivial. I am trying to add a new page to my navigation bar. So apart from **About** and **Home** I am trying to add a **blog** page.
In order to do that I have added all the according spreadsheets css to the right html and I uploaded my new pages accordingly via FTP but it doesn't work!

I think I have done everything correctly but for some reason it doesn't work and I can't seem to make it work!

**The website is www.hoodoopro.com**

Any help would be more than welcome!

```css
.page-marketing-standard {

}

/* .page-marketing-standard .heading {
 font-size: 40px;
 font-size: 2.182rem;
 line-height: 1.042;
} */

.page-marketing-standard .heading + h2 {
 font-size: 1.6rem;
}

@media ( min-width: 480px ) {
 .page-marketing-standard .heading + h2 {
  font-size: 2.182rem;
 }
}

.hero-careers {
 position: relative;
 
 padding: 0;

 height: auto;

 border-bottom: 1px solid #dfe0e1;

 background: #fff;
 color: inherit;

}

/* adjust hero height with header and adjusted for border-bottom */

@media ( min-width: 992px ) {

 .hero-careers { 
  height: 80%;
  /* height: calc(100% - 135px); */
  min-height: 590px;
  max-height: 800px;
 }

}

@media ( min-width: 1200px ) {
 
 .hero-careers { 
  height: calc(100% - 145px);
  max-height: 800px;
 }

}

@media ( min-width: 1320px ) {
 
 .hero-careers { 
  height: calc(100% - 154px);
 }

}

.hero-careers > .container {

 padding-top: 30px;
 padding-bottom: 185px;

 background: url("../img/hero.jpg") 140px 100% no-repeat;
 background-size: 240px;
}


@media ( min-width: 400px ) {
 .hero-careers > .container {
  background-position: 100% 100%;

  padding-bottom: 200px;
 }
}

@media ( min-width: 568px ) {
 .hero-careers > .container {
  background-position: 100% 100%;

  background-size: 50%;
 }
}

@media ( min-width: 768px ) {

 .hero-careers > .container {
  padding-top: 50px;

  background-size: 46%;
  background-position: 100% 100%;
 }

}

@media ( min-width: 992px ) {

 .hero-careers > .container {
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;

  background-size: 55%;
  background-position: 100% 100%;
 }

}

@media ( min-width: 1200px ) {

 .hero-careers > .container {
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: 100% 30px;
 }

}

@media ( min-width: 768px ) {

 .hero-careers h1 span {
  white-space: nowrap;
 }

}

@media ( max-width: 767px ) {
 .hero-careers p {
  max-width: 280px;
 }
}

@media ( max-width: 767px ) {
 .hero-careers .v-align-parent {
  max-width: 600px;

  margin-left: 0;

 }
}



@media ( min-width: 768px ) and ( max-height: 849px ), (max-width: 767px ) and ( max-height: 520px ) {
 .page-careers .hint-arrow-contrast {
  position: fixed;
 }

}


/* carousel slides */

.carousel-item {
 height: 0;

 padding-bottom: 75%;

 background-position: 50% 50%;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
}

@media ( min-width: 568px ) {
 .carousel-item {
  padding-bottom: 62.5%;
 }
}

@media ( min-width: 768px ) {
 .carousel-item {
  padding-bottom: 50%;
 }
}

@media ( min-width: 1690px ) {
 .carousel-item {
  height: 840px;

  padding-bottom: 0;
 }
}

.active .carousel-item {
 
}

/* listings */

.level-careers-overview {
 padding-bottom: 0;
}

.vacancy-profile {
 max-width: 280px;

 -webkit-transform: translateX(30px);
 transform: translateX(30px);

}

@media ( min-width: 768px ) {
 .vacancy-profile {
  max-width: 100%;
 }
}

@media ( min-width: 992px ) {
 .vacancy-profile {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -80px;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(60px);
  transform: translateX(60px);
  z-index: -1;
 }

}

@media ( min-width: 768px ) and ( max-width: 991px ) {

 .level-careers-overview .inline-tabs {
  display: block;
 }
 
}

.level-careers-overview blockquote {
 margin: 0 0 2em;

 font-style: italic;
 color: #2a2a2a;
}

.level-careers-overview blockquote p {
 margin-bottom: 20px;
}

@media ( min-width: 768px ) {
 .level-careers-overview blockquote p {
 margin-bottom: 30px;
 }
}

.level-careers-overview blockquote p:before {
 content: '\201C';

 font-style: normal;
}

.level-careers-overview blockquote p:after {
 position: relative;

 content: '\201D';

 vertical-align: baseline;
}

@media ( min-width: 768px ) {
 .level-careers-overview blockquote p:before {
  margin-left: -.9em;
  padding-right: .5em;
 }

 .level-careers-overview blockquote p:after {
  padding-left: .4em;
  top: 1ex;
 }

}

.level-careers-overview cite {
 display: block;

 opacity: .3;
 
 font-weight: 700;
 font-style: normal;
 font-size: 14px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}

@media ( max-width: 767px ) {
 .level-career-listings {
  padding-bottom: 60px;
 }
}


.level-career-listings .inline-tabs {
 display: block;
}

.level-career-listings .post.active,
.level-career-listings .post .entry {
 padding-bottom: 20px;

 border-bottom: 1px solid #f6f6f6;
}

/* individual job posts */
.level-career-listings .post .entry {
 margin-bottom: 20px;
}

@media ( min-width: 992px ) {

 .level-career-listings .post .entry {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
 }

}

.level-career-listings .post .entry:last-child {
 padding-bottom: 0;
 margin-bottom: 0;

 border: 0;
}
```

```html
wor<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lte IE 9]><html class="no-js is-ie"><![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--><html class=no-js><!--<![endif]-->
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="description" content="">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
 
 
 <title>News</title>
 <link rel=stylesheet href="css/main.css">
 <link rel=stylesheet href="css/owl.carousel.css">
 <link rel=stylesheet href="css/about.css">
 <link rel=stylesheet href="css/blog.css">

 <!--[if lte IE 8]>
 <link rel=stylesheet href="css/ie.css">
 <![endif]-->
  <script src="js/vendor/modernizr.js"></script>
 
  <script src="js/vendor/respond.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body class="page-careers">

<div class="header">
 <div class="container rel text-left">
  <a class="brand brand-color" href="index.html"></a>

    <nav class=nav>
   <ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a>
    <li class="active"><a href="about.html">About</a>
    <li class="active"><a href="blog.html">Blog</a>
   </ul>
  </nav>
 </div>
</div> 


<div class="level level-hero hero-careers has-hint">

 <div class="container full-height">

  <div class="v-align-parent">
   <div class="v-center">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-5">
      <h1 class="mb-30 xs-mb-10 scaled"><span>We are Product Experts.</span> <br class="hidden-sm"> Your product is our priority</h1>
      <p class="mb-30 xs-mb-20">We are a team of experienced Product Managers educated in Berkeley and Stanford, some of us ex-Consultants, that want to work on innovative products.
      We want to put our expertise in use for the most challenging startups.

      <p><a class="btn btn-prepend btn-shadow btn-scroll" href="#">
        <i class="prepended icon-arrow-down"></i><span class="btn-txt">Learn More</span>
       </a>
     </div>
    </div>

   </div>
  </div>

 </div> 

 <div class="hint-arrow hint-arrow-contrast"></div>

</div>

<div class="level no-border">
 <div class="container">

  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3">
    <h1 class="mb-25 sm-mb-20 heading scaled color-dark heading-bordered bordered-above">It is time to give a startup a change</h1>
    
    <h2 class="text-center w-300 color-dark mb-70 sm-mb-40 xs-mb-20">Who are we?</h2>
   </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row mb-60 xs-mb-20">
  
   <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-2 xs-mb-20">
    <div class="has-icon">
     <!-- <i class="icon icon-laptop"></i -->
     <h3 class="mb-25 md-mb-10">Chantal Marin</h3>
     <p class="smaller">Co-founder.Serial Entrepreneur.Co-founder @Letsapp @Weeleo @DroneAdventures @GymLess. MsC CS at UCL. BS EECS at UC Berkeley. See more at: https://uk.linkedin.com/in/chantalmarin

    </div>
   </div>
   
   <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
    <div class="has-icon">
     <!--<i class="icon icon-phone"></i> -->
     <h3 class="mb-25 md-mb-10">Marily Nika</h3>
     <p class="smaller"></p>PM @Google. PhD of Computer Science at Imperial College in London.
    </div>
   </div>
  
  </div>

  <div class="row xs-mb-20">
  
   <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-2 xs-mb-20">
    <div class="has-icon">
     <!--<i class="icon icon-flame"></i> -->
     <h3 class="mb-25 md-mb-10">Marc Molins</h3>
     <p class="smaller"></p>Product Manager at Rocket Internet. Serial Entrepreneur. BS in Telecom engineering.
     See more at: https://es.linkedin.com/in/marcmolinsgracia/en 

    </div>
   </div>
   
   <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
    <div class="has-icon">
     <!-- <i class="icon icon-camera"></i> -->
     <h3 class="mb-25 md-mb-10"></h3>
     <p class="smaller"></p>
    </div>
   </div>
  
  </div>

 </div>

</div>

<div class="carousel">
 <div class="carousel-item" style="background-image: url('img/slide-1.jpg')">

 </div>
 <div class="carousel-item" style="background-image: url('img/slide-3.jpg')">

 </div>
 <div class="carousel-item" style="background-image: url('img/slide-2.jpg')">

 </div>
</div>

<div class="level">

 <div class="container">

  <div class="row">

   <div class="col-md-6 text-center">
    <img src="img/ceo.jpg" width="90%">

   </div>

   <div class="col-md-6">
    <h2>Conquer your fears as some of our happy clients say. </h2>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <blockquote>
     Don't wait for your product to be left behind.
    </blockquote>

    <p></p>
   </div>

  </div>


 </div>

</div>





<div class="footer text-center">
 <p>
  <a href="index.html">hoodoopro.com</a> | January 2016
 </p>

</div> 
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
<!-- //-beg- concat_js -->
<script src="js/vendor/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
<!-- //-end- concat_js -->
<script>
(function(){


    var windowWidth = function() {
        var e = window, 
        a = 'inner';

        if ( !( 'innerWidth' in window ) ) { 
            a = 'client';
            e = document.documentElement || document.body;
        }
        return e[ a+'Width' ];
    }

    var carouselPadding = function() {

        var limit =  1690; 
        if ( Modernizr.mq("( min-width: " + limit + "px ) ") ) {

            padding = Math.round( ( windowWidth() - limit ) / 2 );

        }

        else {
            
            padding = 0;
        
        }

        return padding;
    };

    var owl = $(".carousel");
    
    owl.owlCarousel({
     
        items : 1,
        loop : true,
        // margin : 10,
        nav : false,
        dots : true,
        responsive :  {
            0  : {
                stagePadding : 0
            },
            1690 : {
                stagePadding : carouselPadding(),
                margin : 30
            },
        }
    });

    $('.owl-item:not(".active")').on('click', function(e) {

     if ( $(this).next().is('.active') ) {
   owl.trigger('next.owl.carousel');
     }

     else {
   owl.trigger('prev.owl.carousel');
     }
    });


}());


</script>


 
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3vOfo.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you have to find where the HTML of the navigation is and add a new anchor tag (`<a>`) that directs to the blog page.

`<a href="blog.html">Blog</a>`

---

### index.html

Find the following code:

```
<p class="fmenu">
   <a href="index.html">HOME</a> | <a href="about.html">ABOUT</a>
</p>
```

Replace with:

```
<p class="fmenu">
   <a href="index.html">HOME</a> | <a href="about.html">ABOUT</a> | <a href="blog.html">BLOG</a>
</p>
```

---

### about.html

Find the following code:

```
<nav class="nav">
   <ul>
      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li class="active"><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
   </ul>
</nav>
```

Replace with:

```
<nav class="nav">
   <ul>
      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li class="active"><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="blog.html">Blog</a></li>
   </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Yes I already did those changes and it still doesn't work. Locally I can see the results correctly but once I push the website via FTP and I go into my site it doesn't appear. Any idea why is tha

Comment: Are you sure that when you upload the files via FTP you accept the overriding?